# moving jupyter (ihaskell) folder off of dropbox

Tags: dropbox, jupyter, ihaskell

I have been working with Jupyter notebooks in a directory inside of my dropbox.  (This work is actually in IHaskell, but I am not sure if this is relevant.)

The folder got too big for dropbox, and so I moved it out.  After that, I can't get the kernel to start on any notebooks. It dies and dies.

It seems that moving the folder that contained IHaskell has messed up my installation.

Do I have to re-install everything, or is there a fix?

Answer (score 1):

> It dies and dies

If the `IHaskell` kernel keeps dying, I would follow the suggestion mentioned on the IHaskell Troubleshooting guide (last paragraph of the [homepage](https://github.com/gibiansky/IHaskell/tree/7a41fa209d071cf7ff7c4e63dbc9f584006efb0d#troubleshooting)), especially the "kernel keeps dying" paragraph:

> If you've e.g. installed an lts-10 IHaskell and are using it with an
>   lts-9 project the mismatch between GHC 8.2 and GHC 8.0 will cause this
>   error.

If this is your case, I would:

#### Verify that the `haskell` kernel is available

```
$ jupyter kernelspec list
Available kernels:
  haskell    [...]/kernels/haskell      <-- OK
  scala      [...]/kernels/scala
  python3    [...]/kernels/python3
```

#### Verify that the `ghc` version is matching

```
$ cat [...]/kernels/haskell/kernel.json
.../.stack/programs/.../ghc-X.Y.Z/lib/ghc-X.Y.Z"...

$ stack ghc -- --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version X.Y.Z
```

#### If the versions mismatch

> Stack also has the notion of a 'global project' located at
>   ~/.stack/global-project/ and the stack.yaml for that project should be
>   on the same LTS as the version of IHaskell installed to avoid this
>   issue.

I would keep the `lts-A.B` consistent:

```
$ cat #HOME/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml
...
resolver: lts-A.B

$ stack install ihaskell --resolver lts-A.B
```

To choose the `lts-A.B` / `ghc-X.Y.Z` combinations right for you, you can simply use https://www.stackage.org/lts-A.B

---

*Today, for instance, you can simply use the `lts-11.4`*